# how to send extra context in wagtail Page

Tags: python, django, wagtail

Currently I Am Using Like This But Nothing Works.... I tried to check in Both the Classes but nothing works (UserPage and UserPageCarousel) But Nothing Works .

```
class UserPageCarousel(Orderable):
    def get_context_data(self, request):
        context = super(UserPageCarousel, self).get_context(request)
        products = UserPageCarousel.objects.all()
        print(products)
        n = len(products)
        nslides = n // 4 + ceil((n / 4) - (n // 4))

        context['no_of_slides'] = nslides
        context['range'] = range(1, nslides)
        context['product'] = products
        return context
    page = ParentalKey("user.UserPage", related_name="carousel_videos", null=True)
    carousel_video = models.ForeignKey(
        "wagtailvideos.Video",
        related_name="+",
        null=True,
        blank=False,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

    panels = [
        VideoChooserPanel('carousel_video')

    ]

class UserPage(Page):
    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        MultiFieldPanel([
            InlinePanel('carousel_videos', label="Video")
        ], heading="Add Videos To List")
    ]
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "User Page"
        verbose_name_plural = "User Pages"
```

and here is my template (path is  user/user_page.html)
Code:-

```
<p> Welcome Hi  </p>
{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
    {{ user.username }}
{% endif %}
{% for loop_cycle in self.carousel_videos.all %}
   <p>{{ loop_cycle.carousel_video.url }}</p>
{% endfor %}

{% for  i in range %}
  <p> {{ i }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

All Template Code is Running But for i in range gives nothing Means my get context is not working in any case

Current Output: -

```
Welcome Hi Hahaha

puneet
/media/original_videos/horse_rolling_farm_animal_equine_1067.mp4

/media/original_videos/horse_rolling_farm_animal_equine_1067_ME9ybb0.mp4

/media/original_videos/horse_rolling_farm_animal_equine_1067_Ix4pCIa.mp4

/media/original_videos/Horses_2.mp4

/media/original_videos/horse_rolling_farm_animal_equine_1067_rhDf82J.mp4
```

Comment: It looks like there is an extra space in your for loop. {% for i in range %}

Answer (score 0):

Your `get_context` method should be on the Page object (`UserPage`), not the child object on it - and it should be named `get_context`, not `get_context_data`.